# AWS Cognito Software Token MFA works once, then unexpectedly reverts to SMS MFA for all future logins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, multi-factor-authentication, totp

### Background:

I have a React web app (utilizing `aws-amplify`) which is connecting to/using an AWS Cognito User Pool for auth.

I am trying to enable MFA and, more specifically, I want my users to have the option to utilize Software Token TOTP MFA (i.e. Google Authenticator, or similar, app).

When I set my User Pool to have MFA required, I am forced to enable SMS MFA and then Software TOTP is optional. In my case, I have TOTP enabled.

In my web app, I have added the necessary component via:

```js
import { SelectMFAType } from 'aws-amplify-react';

# other code

<SelectMFAType authData={user} MFATypes={{ SMS: true, TOTP: true }} />

# other code
```

If you're unfamiliar with `aws-amplify-react` and/or `SelectMFAType`, this component provides a UI element where the user can choose if they prefer to use SMS or Software TOTP as their MFA method. If they choose SMS, their previously-verified phone number is used and everything works.

If the user chooses TOTP, they are shown a QR code to scan in the authenticator app of their choice and they are prompted with an input field to enter a 6-digit number from the authenticator app to verify TOTP.
This is all very standard for anyone who has used a TOTP MFA option on any other website. If the user enters a correct code from the app, their TOTP choice is verified.

In short `SelectMFAType` is just a shortcut/stand-in to quickly prototype and test without needing to create a custom component.

### Problem:

Now, here's the problem and how to reproduce it. (The starting point is a user who has just enabled TOTP.):

1. User logs out.
2. User logs in.
3. If correct username/password, user is prompted for TOTP.
4. If correct TOTP, user is logged in. **This is working perfectly so far, but it won't stay that way.**
5. User logs out.
6. User logs in.
7. If correct username/password, user is prompted for SMS MFA and will receive a text message with 6-digit code. **This is the unexpected behavior. I expect it to continue requesting TOTP MFA from their authenticator app unless the user changes their preferred method back to SMS.**
8. From this point forward, the user will only ever be asked for SMS MFA.

In between step 4 and step 7, the user's preference was not changed. Absolutely nothing changed in the React app or in the AWS User Pool settings.

Further, if I interrogate the user via the AWS CLI command
`aws cognito-idp admin-get-user --user-pool-id ${MY_ID} --username ${MY_USER_NAME}`, I can confirm that the user's MFA preference is exactly what I expect:

```
{
    <other irrelevant keys redacted>
    "PreferredMfaSetting": "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA",
    "UserMFASettingList": [
        "SMS_MFA",
        "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA"
    ]
}
```

The MFA challenge is an API response from AWS Cognito when the user attempts to authenticate and it is either `SMS_MFA` or `SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA`. In my case, I get a single `SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA` challenge, but then all future challenges revert, against my wishes, to `SMS_MFA`.

If I repeat the TOTP setup process (delete the entry from authenticator app, re-verify, etc.), I can repeat all of the steps again. By that, I mean the MFA will expect TOTP one time and then again revert back to SMS after that first time.

Can anyone shed light on this situation? Have you experienced it? Is it a known issue/bug in AWS Cognito? Am I doing something wrong? I feel like if this was broken, there would be a pretty big amount of noise being generated, but I can't find anyone else with the same issue.

### Things I have tried:

- Searched extensively for anyone else with the same issue here, Google, and the AWS forums.
- I have posted on the AWS forums, but that has gone nowhere:  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=324131
- Created a custom component to replace `SelectMFAType` under the theory that there was something wrong with the implementation in `aws-amplify-react`. I will paste that custom component at the bottom of this question as a reference.
- Completely destroyed and re-created the AWS Cognito User Pool. I thought perhaps it was corrupted or otherwise not working. This made no difference.

### `SetupTOTP.js` Component:

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContextText,
  DialogTitle,
  TextField,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { ToastsStore } from 'react-toasts';
import QRCode from 'qrcode.react';

import { AuthStateContext } from 'Context/auth-context';

const SetupTOTP = React.memo(props => {
  const { open, handleClose } = props;
  const { username } = useContext(AuthStateContext);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [qrCode, setQrCode] = useState('');
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');

  const handleSave = () => {
    Auth.verifyTotpToken(user, token)
      .then(() => {
        Auth.setPreferredMFA(user, 'TOTP').then(() => {
          ToastsStore.success('Token Verified Updated');
          handleClose();
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        ToastsStore.error(err.message);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
      setUser(user);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (username && user) {
      Auth.setupTOTP(user).then(code => {
        setQrCode(
          `otpauth://totp/AWSCognito:${username}?secret=${code}&issuer=REDACTED`
        );
      });
    }
  }, [username, user]);

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
    >
      <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Change Password</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <QRCode value={qrCode} />

        <TextField
          margin="dense"
          id="name"
          label="Verify Token"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          onChange={e => setToken(e.target.value)}
        />
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={handleSave} color="primary">
          Save
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
});

export default SetupTOTP;
```

Comment: I have now run into this with two users. Any progress on this? It seems like a pretty bad bug to enable Software MFA and have it skipped, as occurs when I turn of SMS MFA and leave software enabled (on the random users where this occurs).

Comment: Unfortunately not from me. I had to abandon the effort. I tried using SMS MFA instead, but SMS delivery to T-Mobile customers is not reliable, so I had to abandon that as well. 

Instead, I am using 3 Cognito Lambda triggers (auth challenge define, create, and verify) to implement my own email-based MFA. 

I believe you could take a similar approach to implement a custom software token TOTP as well, but email actually was the best fit for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in Cognito. See this [Amplify issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1226).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am unsure if that's the same issue that was plaguing me. As you can see from my sample SetupTOTP code, I was invoking `setPreferredMfa` after the call to `verifyTotpToken`. The other difference is that my app was not falling back to no MFA, but rather falling back to SMS MFA. That user seems to say that their app was not doing any MFA at all: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1226#issuecomment-404943954 . It could be the same bug, I'm just not sure and as I mentioned above, I sidestepped the issue by making my own MFA solution.